# Загрузка файлов из операционной системы

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, css

Всем привет.Такая задача: "Нужно методом перетаскивания из операционной системы загружать файлы на сервер через **AJAX**".Загрузку нужно производить не в один блок с конкретным **id**,а с **div**'ами или **tr**'ами, у которых проставлен некий класс.Аналог **Dropbox**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Это называется drag & drop.

Мне тоже нужно было подобное реализовать, очень понравилась статья: [HTML5 Drag and Drop загрузка файлов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125424/)

Comment: Не могу обратиться по class! Не работает. Делаю: var dropZone = $(".dropzones");

Есть соображения, как сделать несколько областей для загрузки, а не одну?

Comment: var dropZone = []; $(".dropzones").each(function(){ dropZone.push($(this)); });  
селектором класса вы достаете множество, а не переменную - запихните их в массив к примеру